# Changing the elements of an array member of a const object

Tags: c++, arrays, class, vector, constants

Can anyone explain to me why the following code works:

```
#include <iostream>
class Vec 
{
    int *_vec;
    unsigned int _size;

public:
Vec (unsigned int size) : _vec (new int [size]), _size(size) {};
int & operator[] (const int & i) 
{
    return _vec[i];
}
int & operator[] (const int & i) const 
{
    return _vec[i];
}
};

int main () 
{
    const Vec v (3);
    v[1] = 15;
    std::cout << v[1] << std::endl;
}
```

It compiles and runs just fine, even though we're changing the contents of a const object. How is that okay?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constness is with regards to the members of the class. You cannot change the value of `v._vec`, but there's no problem changing the content of the memory that `v._vec` points to.

Comment: So would it be better for the const operator[] to return a const int& ?

Comment: @azphare yes, `v[1] = 15;` is then a compiler error. Btw, don't forget a destructor with `delete [] _vec`.